# MVC: Ajax Webgrid of Partial view paging and sorting

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, partial-views, webgrid

In my partial view I have upload document and ajax webgrid which displays the document that is uploaded.
This is my partial view `Upload_doc.cshtml`,

```
@{
    WebGrid doc_upload = new WebGrid(null, rowsPerPage: 5, fieldNamePrefix: "g1", pageFieldName: "p1",
    ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid");
    doc_upload.Bind(Model.documents, autoSortAndPage: true, rowCount: 5);
}

<div id="ajaxgrid">
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning"/>
      <div >
                @doc_upload.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid" }, tableStyle: "table table-bordered", mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
    firstText: "<< First",
    previousText: "< Prev",
    nextText: "Next >",
    lastText: "Last >>", columns: doc_upload.Columns(
        doc_upload.Column("sno", "Serial No.", canSort: true),
        doc_upload.Column("docdesc", "Document Title"),
        doc_upload.Column("docdt", "Document Date", format: (k) => k.docdt != null ? string.Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", k.docdt) : ""),
        doc_upload.Column(header: "Actions", format: (item) =>
        new HtmlString(
           Html.ActionLink("View", "ViewDoc", new { sno=item.sno}, new { target = "_blank" }) + "    " +
           Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "delete",
           new { sno=item.sno }, new AjaxOptions
           {

               UpdateTargetId = "test",
               InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
           })
                )
                    )

        ))
            </div>
```

My problem is:-

case(i) When I click on header to sort, whole page does postback as it excutes Index page and same for paging defeating the purpose of ajax.

case (ii) If I upload document and then I sort or do paging, my webgrid disappears.

case(iii) If I delete a document and then I sort or do paging, it will execute delete function again.

So, How to change default loading page of web grid?
Please Help!!! Thank You